# RegistrationIntentService doesn' t get called

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-service

I' m trying to implement push notification in my applicatio but the RegistrationIntentService.class does not get called when i use the method startService.

home activity:

```
    public class HomeActivity extends AriesMobileActivity {

    private LinearLayout itemReports;
    private LinearLayout itemTickets;
    private LinearLayout itemSystems;
    private LinearLayout itemManuals;
    private LinearLayout itemNotes;
    private LinearLayout itemChecklist;
    private LinearLayout itemCalendar;
    private LinearLayout itemSettings;

    private BroadcastReceiver mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
                        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
                boolean sentToken = sharedPreferences
                        .getBoolean(Preferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, false);
                if (sentToken) {

                } else {

                }
            }


        };


            GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
            int resultCode = apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
            if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
                if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {
                    apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(this, resultCode, 9000)
                            .show();
                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
                    finish();
                }

            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,RegistrationIntentService.class);
            startService(intent);





        if(this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
            this.setContentView(R.layout.layout_home_landscape);
        else this.setContentView(R.layout.layout_home_portrait);

        itemReports = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.item_menu_reports);
        itemTickets = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.item_menu_tickets);
        itemSystems = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.item_menu_systems);
        itemManuals = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.item_menu_manuals);
        itemNotes = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.item_menu_notes);
        itemChecklist = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.item_menu_checklist);
        itemCalendar = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.item_menu_calendar);
        itemSettings = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.item_menu_settings);



        itemReports.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, ReportListActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        itemTickets.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, TicketListActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        itemSystems.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, SystemListActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        itemSettings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                context.startActivity(new Intent(context, SettingsActivity.class));
            }
        });

        itemManuals.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, ManualsListActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        itemCalendar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, CalendarActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });



    }

     @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver,
                    new IntentFilter(Preferences.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver);
            super.onPause();
        }

}
```

RegistrationIntentService:

```
    public class RegistrationIntentService extends IntentService {

    private static final String[] TOPICS = {"global"};

    public RegistrationIntentService() {
        super("RegistrationIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        try {
            // [START register_for_gcm]
            // Initially this call goes out to the network to retrieve the token, subsequent calls
            // are local.
            // R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId (the Sender ID) is typically derived from google-services.json.
            // See https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start for details on this file.
            // [START get_token]
            InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
            String token = instanceID.getToken("312109676786",
                    GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
            // [END get_token]
            Log.i("RegistrationIntentService", "GCM Registration Token: " + token);

            // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
            sendRegistrationToServer(token);

            // Subscribe to topic channels
            subscribeTopics(token);

            // You should store a boolean that indicates whether the generated token has been
            // sent to your server. If the boolean is false, send the token to your server,
            // otherwise your server should have already received the token.
            sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(Preferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, true).apply();
            // [END register_for_gcm]
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("RegistrationIntentService", "Failed to complete token refresh", e);
            // If an exception happens while fetching the new token or updating our registration data
            // on a third-party server, this ensures that we'll attempt the update at a later time.
            sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(Preferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, false).apply();
        }
        // Notify UI that registration has completed, so the progress indicator can be hidden.
        Intent registrationComplete = new Intent(Preferences.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(registrationComplete);
    }

    /**
     * Persist registration to third-party servers.
     *
     * Modify this method to associate the user's GCM registration token with any server-side account
     * maintained by your application.
     *
     * @param token The new token.
     */
    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // Add custom implementation, as needed.
    }

    /**
     * Subscribe to any GCM topics of interest, as defined by the TOPICS constant.
     *
     * @param token GCM token
     * @throws IOException if unable to reach the GCM PubSub service
     */
    // [START subscribe_topics]
    private void subscribeTopics(String token) throws IOException {
        GcmPubSub pubSub = GcmPubSub.getInstance(this);
        for (String topic : TOPICS) {
            pubSub.subscribe(token, "/topics/" + topic, null);
        }
    }
    // [END subscribe_topics]
```

manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ngs.ariesmobile"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.verivo.examples.pushandalerttests.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:name=".AriesMobileApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar" >

        <service
            android:name=".AriesMobileGcmListenerService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name=".AriesMobileInstanceIDListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service android:name=".RegistrationIntentService" android:exported="false">
          <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
          </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.example.gcm" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.verivo.examples.pushandalerttests.MyBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

                <category android:name="com.verivo.examples.pushandalerttests" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name=".receivers.PhoneCallReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".view.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".view.HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name=".view.SignatureCaptureActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" />
        <activity
            android:name=".view.SetupHomeActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name=".view.SetupApiActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name=".view.SetupLoginActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name=".view.SetupTechnicianActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name=".view.SettingsActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name=".view.SettingsPasswordActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name=".view.SettingsApiActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name=".view.SynchronizationActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name=".view.ReportCustomerActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" />
        <activity
            android:name=".view.ReportInternalActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" />
        <activity
            android:name=".view.ReportListActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name=".view.TicketListActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name=".view.PhoneCallActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
        <activity
            android:name=".view.SystemActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
        <activity
            android:name=".view.SystemListActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name=".view.ReportSummaryActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".view.ManualsListActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_manuals_list" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".view.SystemStoricalActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_system_storical" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".view.SystemTechnicalPartActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_system_technical_part" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".view.SystemConsActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_system_cons" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".view.SystemNoteActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_system_note" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".view.SystemSupervisionActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_system_supervision" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".view.CalendarActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_calendar"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".view.ReportHoursActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_report_hours" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ngs.ariesmobile.pushnotification.RegisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_register" >
        </activity>



    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: In the manifest entry for `RegistrationIntentService` you include an intent filter.  Because you are starting the service with an explicit intent, the filter is not needed and may be interfering with resolution.  The [manifest in the GCM sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml) does not have an intent filter for the service. Try removing the filter to see if that helps. Also add a Log statement in `HomeActivity` where you call `startService` to confirm that code is executing.

Comment: Also check the Java package of your RegistrationIntentService matches the manifest